# How to indicate number of occurrences that have happened before and after an event

Tags: r

For any given row I want to know how many x-events away that row is from the first time a y-event occurs in my data set, either before the y-event ( - ) or after the y-event ( + ).

As it pertains to my data set the x-events are the rows where df$type = "ES". The y-event is the first time where df$type = "PH".

I've found a solution that works, wherein I use a case_when() but I'd like to know if there is a more elegant solution.

```r
library(tidyverse)
# What I have 

df <- data.frame(
  type = c("ES", "OT", "ES", "PH", "ES", "PH", "OT", "ES"),
  bef_aft_PH = c(-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4),
  rownum_at_PH = c(4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4),
  date = as.POSIXct(c("2019/01/01", "2019/01/05", "2019/01/15", "2019/02/19", "2019/03/11", "2019/03/22", "2019/04/20", "2019/05/01"))
)

df
#>   type bef_aft_PH rownum_at_PH       date
#> 1   ES         -3            4 2019-01-01
#> 2   OT         -2            4 2019-01-05
#> 3   ES         -1            4 2019-01-15
#> 4   PH          0            4 2019-02-19
#> 5   ES          1            4 2019-03-11
#> 6   PH          2            4 2019-03-22
#> 7   OT          3            4 2019-04-20
#> 8   ES          4            4 2019-05-01


# Non-elegant Solution
df %>% 
  mutate(EScumsum = cumsum(type == "ES"),
         ES_bef_aft_PH = case_when(
           bef_aft_PH < 0 ~ as.double(x = EScumsum - (EScumsum[match("PH", .$type)] + 1)), 
           bef_aft_PH == 0 ~ as.double(x = EScumsum - EScumsum),
           bef_aft_PH > 0 ~ as.double(x = EScumsum - EScumsum[match("PH", .$type)])
         ))
#>   type bef_aft_PH rownum_at_PH       date EScumsum ES_bef_aft_PH
#> 1   ES         -3            4 2019-01-01        1            -2
#> 2   OT         -2            4 2019-01-05        1            -2
#> 3   ES         -1            4 2019-01-15        2            -1
#> 4   PH          0            4 2019-02-19        2             0
#> 5   ES          1            4 2019-03-11        3             1
#> 6   PH          2            4 2019-03-22        3             1
#> 7   OT          3            4 2019-04-20        3             1
#> 8   ES          4            4 2019-05-01        4             2
```

I hadn't anticipated needing to wrap all of the RHS arguments of the case_when in as.double() so I'm interested in knowing why I needed to do that as well.

Comment: Not clear. Can you explain how first two rows have `ES_bef_aft_PH = -2` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>%
  mutate(ES_PH1cumsum  = cumsum(type == "ES" | bef_aft_PH == 0)) %>%
  mutate(ES_bef_aft_PH = ES_PH1cumsum - ES_PH1cumsum[match(0, .$bef_aft_PH)])


  type bef_aft_PH rownum_at_PH       date ES_PH1cumsum ES_bef_aft_PH
1   ES         -3            4 2019-01-01            1            -2
2   OT         -2            4 2019-01-05            1            -2
3   ES         -1            4 2019-01-15            2            -1
4   PH          0            4 2019-02-19            3             0
5   ES          1            4 2019-03-11            4             1
6   PH          2            4 2019-03-22            4             1
7   OT          3            4 2019-04-20            4             1
8   ES          4            4 2019-05-01            5             2
```